# Centering 3 or more components in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I want to have equally centered* 3 objects in my GUI and through I expect there is an easy solution, I just couldn' t find out how to make it right.

*In other words: I want to make the distance between every component' s centre (and borders) equal.

What I' ve tried:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class App {

    public static void launchView(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello");
        JButton b = new JButton("Help me");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("2015-08-06 - 2015-09-32");

        frame.add(l, "pos 0.25al 0.5al");
        frame.add(b, "pos 0.5al 0.5al");
        frame.add(l2, "pos 0.75al 0.5al");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               launchView();
           }
       });
   }
}
```

[image: Effect]

In the picture You can see that date is to close to center, while there is a lot of free space at right side - it' s not centered.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define column constraints to archive this. In the following Code i define 3 columns and they all grow equally. 
For each column i add a component and define its algin to be 50% in x- and 50% in y direction.
You can disable the debug mode (dotted bordes around the cells) by removing the "debug" option from the Layout Constraints.

```
public class App {

    public static void launchView(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx, filly, debug", // Layout Constraints
                                "[grow][grow][grow]", // Column Constraints
                                "")); // Row Constraints
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello");
        JButton b = new JButton("Help me");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("2015-08-06 - 2015-09-32");

        frame.add(l, "align 50% 50%");
        frame.add(b, "align 50% 50%");
        frame.add(l2, "align 50% 50%");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
        public void run() {
               launchView();
           }
       });
   }
}
```

[image]